# CSS3 Transitions with Anchors

Tags: html, css, anchor, transition

I can't get this anchor transition to work! Please tell me what you think.

**Here's the CSS**

```
a.transition {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

**And here's the HTML**

```
<h1 id="intro">Let's Build Something... </h1>
<h1 id="intro2"><a class="transition" href="#create">Together</a>.</h1>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

<p><a name="create" class="transition">My name is Geoff Phillips, and I'm an innovator. What can I create for you?<a/></p>
```

Comment: What transition..? You're not adding any css properties to transform over. Try adding a hover pseudo-class with color properties (as well as a copy of those transition properties).

Comment: I believe you are attempting to animate the window scrolling to the anchor when a link is clicked, correct? This is not possible with CSS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think you can do it with just CSS. Here's a function to achieve it with jQuery:

```
$('a[href^=#]').on("click",function(e){
    var t= $(this.hash);
    var t=t.length&&t||$('[name='+this.hash.slice(1)+']');
    if(t.length){
        var tOffset=t.offset().top;
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:tOffset-20},'slow');
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});​
```

This will work with any `<a href="#any-id-or-name">` anchor.
**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/2YfzC/)**.

To make it scroll faster or slower, change `'slow'` to `'fast'` or any numeric value in milliseconds.

Comment: I tried implementing this (which is exactly what I needed) but it still won't work. It worked in your demo, so I'm not sure why it won't work on my site.

Comment: Have you included jQuery in your `head` section? Add this code: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js"></script>`

Comment: Yeah, that's there. Maybe something else is messing it up. www.geoffphillips.me/version2.0

Comment: Which version @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas ? Maybe i can't use `target` as a variable name, check it now: http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/2YfzC/

Comment: It does work in chrome in the demo, that's what I'm using. You just need to add some more "<br/>" so that it has room to scroll down.

Comment: @NashBridges try with the new version...again ;) i see it's throwing an "unexpected token ILLEGAL" error

Comment: @NashBridges CTRL + SHIFT + J then move to the Console tab (in Chrome). Let me check for typos

Comment: That doesn't work either. I got the last set of code to work without throwing an error by just erasing and re-typing the last line (line 17). But it didn't make the code work.

Comment: Ok, let's focus on something else. Try to download this js file http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js and upload it to your site, so that you can include it with `<script type="text/javascript" src="/path-to-your-js-folder/jquery.js"></script>`

Comment: @NashBridges ...and still not working :( so, maybe it's because of your doctype. Try to add `type="text/javascript"` to the `<script>` tag, or to move it just before the closing `</body>` tag

Comment: That did it!!! You're a genius! The closing body tag thing. That gives those elements time to load or something?

Comment: @NashBridges well, i just guessed so i'm not that genius ;-) probably it's related to your doctype restrictions. Consider moving to html5's `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` in future!

Comment: My next question was going to be, "Could this be a doctype issue?" I just switched to 5...

Answer (score 0):

You can scroll to any element of a page with the [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) JavaScript method. It is available on any element.
`document.getElementById("yourElement").scrollIntoView();` will scroll to `yourElement`. With Firefox, you can even scroll smoothly by adding `{behavior:'smooth'}` as a param of the method. This is not cross-browser unfortunately.

If you want a cross-browser VanillaJS lib, I would recommend [Smooth-scroll](https://github.com/cferdinandi/smooth-scroll)