# Background Scrolling layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, layout, scroll, fixed

Basically, I am creating a web page for my school project... sorry for silly explanation but..

I want to have fixed navigation bar at the top of the site and when you click any link it will move you up or down to the requested content (not to different subpage, just scrolling up/down)..

see example here: http://www.danbrown.com/

however I need just the simplest way how to do it...and I didnt find any tutorial whatsoever.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use fixed position for you menu.
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

And to scroll to a particular spot in the page use link anchor.
http://www.echoecho.com/htmllinks08.htm

I could code the ole thing for you but you will learn nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Link anchors are totally the easiest and most reliable way to do what you want.

`<a name="a">text</a>` or `<a id="a">text</a>` both set an anchor point somewhere, and `<a href="#a">text</a>` will scroll the viewport to that link.

You can also set the `id` attribute on other elements, say, headings, to make them into anchor targets, but the `name` property will only work on `<a>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point, you could use the following twitter bootstrap demo to do the fixed navigation bar.
The jquery code is just needed to make a scroll animation. It would also work with-out jQuery.
In the demo you should do a change effect to the navigation to show the current scroll position. That's not in the demo.

You can find the same code here at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/nnxfk7s6/).

The initial scroll effect is not difficult to do. Please check my anwser in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27205883/bind-vertical-scroll-position-to-counter/27206281#27206281) that will help you to do that effect.
(You could also do the fixed navigation with the code from the counter example and do your own menu styling.)

```js
$(function () {
    // source for transition animation from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643510/css3-transitions-with-anchors
    $('a[href^=#]').on("click", function (e) {
        var t = $(this.hash);
        var t = t.length && t || $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
        if (t.length) {
            var tOffset = t.offset().top;
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: tOffset - 20
            }, 'slow');
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    min-height: 2000px;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
/* anchor style to scroll to the right position */
 a.anchor {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Fixed navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>

            </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>

        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#dummy1">Dummy 1</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#dummy2">Dummy 2</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>

                </li>
                <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>

                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row"> <a class="anchor" id="dummy1"></a>

         <h1>Dummy 1</h1>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row"> <a class="anchor" id="dummy2"></a>

         <h1>Dummy 2</h1>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,</p>
    </div>
</div>
```